# Zabbix-server Import different version host setting (5.0 -> 4.0)

Tags: zabbix

We were using zabbix-server 5.0 for years, but for some reason, we have to downgrade to zabbix-server 4.0.

So I created a new server, installed zabbix-server 4.0 on it.

There are many hosts, items, triggers, actions... in 5.0.

Since I was importing those settings into 4.0, the error shows below

[image: Error when import 5.0 setting into 4.0]

One way I can do is to config one-by-one.

Is there a smarter way to do it?

Comment: Please, don't. Also, you have to edit the XML by hand.

Comment: Yes, I found it. I think it is better to config one-by-one then edit the XML.